# Typesetting in Devanagari

Tags: packages, indic

I am writing a small part of my code.

```
\documentclass {article}

\usepackage{devanagari}

\begin{document}

{\dn gunottar ani praman}

\end{document}
```

This does not yield me the required output.

What is the solution to this problem?

edit: Texlive 2012 pdflatex produces

[image]

Comment: I ran your example in TeXLive 2012 pdflatex and got the image I'll add to your question (as I can't add it here so easily) is that the correct output?

Comment: i did the same as david did, and authentic-looking devanagari (i don't know the script).  are any errors reported when you process your document, such as failure to find the package or the requisite font?

Answer (score 6):

Save the test file as

```
test.dn
```

and run on it the `devnag` program:

```
devnag test.dn
```

This will produce a `test.tex` file

```
\def\DevnagVersion{2.15}\documentclass {article}

\usepackage{devanagari}

\begin{document}

{\dn \7{g}no\381w\qq{r} aEn \3FEwm\qq{n}}

\end{document}
```

that you can run `pdflatex` on getting what I assume is correct output (but I don't read Devanagari)

[image]

The `devnag test` step must be made every time you modify the `test.dn` file, before doing

```
pdflatex test
```