# Devanagari not rendering properly in Overleaf with pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, devanagari

I am trying to render the Om mani padme hum in Overleaf, and because of other conflicts I'm restricted to using the pdflatex compiler.  From what I can find online, the following should render it cleanly:

```
\def\DevnagVersion{2.17}\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{devanagari}
\begin{document}
{\dn .o ma.ni padme huu/}
\end{document}
```

But this renders:
[image]

When I think it should render something more like

[image]

In particular, it looks like the first character is just what you'd get from {\dn o}, but under the Velthuis Encoding Scheme {\dn .o} is supposed to render the AUM. All of the examples in the devanagari package similarly don't look right.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to preprocess the file. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82982/typesetting-in-devanagari/82985#82985

Comment: I think this is the preprocessed file?  This is the output of devnag.  Is there an example that works in Overleaf?

One issue is that I want these characters as just a few words within a sentence in a large English document, not a standalone document of purely Devanagari script.

Comment: No, this is not the output of the preprocessed file. You should get something like `{\dn : mEZ p\394w\? \8{h}\1}` which would render as expected.

Comment: Thank you!  Not sure what went wrong with the preprocessing!

Comment: You might be able to set up things on Overleaf using `latexmk`, but I have to admit that I am not sure how to do this exactly.

Comment: overcoming the "other conflicts" is likely to be easier than getting reasonable devanagari out of pdflatex.